# How to Resolve USB Host Issue in Android?

Tags: android, usb, android-ndk

I am trying to host a USB Stick to my Android Device using "USB 2.0 Type A to Mini USB 5-Pin Type B Female / Male Adapter". I have two requirements:

1. To Trigger USB stick from my android device.
2. To recieve Data from USB after triggering it.

But Android does not support USB Host. Can anybody tell me what to do in this regard.

Thanks and regards,
Rahul Jaiswal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android devices do not support USB Host mode.

(Well, **a few** devices do, but it certainly isn't a standard feature of the Android SDK. There is no simple solution.)

If you have a Nexus One, you may find [Sven Killig's experiments](http://sven.killig.de/android/N1/2.2/usb_host/) interesting.

Comment: Android SDK now supports USB mode. I would love to see this implemented.